# Visit all subdirectories and extract first page from every pdf

Tags: bash, pdftk

I have a few folders with E-Books and I want to extract first page from every book. There are over two hundred books so doing this manually it's a big pain in the back and will be very time consuming.

I have a command that does the job for single file

```
pdftk TehInput.pdf cat 1 output cover_TehInput.pdf
```

How do I wrap this into a single script that visits everything and assigns the name to output like `cover_wtv-original-name-is.pdf`? All the output files might be everywhere like in the directory where script was started or near the original file.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just loop over `ls`?

Comment: @ssdecontrol: [there's a good reason for that, yes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf This is true when you're writing robust code to deal with someone else's files in contexts you're not in control of, yes. But we all know that parsing `ls` output is often the easiest way for a one-off task on a load of files whose origin you know, and where you're sure there aren't any newlines in the names.

Comment: @ssdecontrol `for i in *.pdf` is in fact shorter to type than `for i in $(ls *.pdf)`. I don't see how the parsing of `ls` is easier than globs!

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Often that's true, but there isn't a quick way of doing `ls -tr | ...` with globs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use no blanks or newlines in filenames:

```
find . -iname '*.pdf' -printf "%h %f\n" | sed -E 's|(.*) (.*)|echo pdftk \1/\2 cat 1 output \1/cover_\2|' | sh
```

If output is okay, remove "echo ".

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `find` command for this. Something like:

```
find . -iname '*.pdf' -exec pdftk '{}' cat 1 output '{}'.cover.pdf ';'
```

This will find all PDFs from the current directory (`.`) downwards, and execute

```
pdftk filename.pdf cat 1 output filename.pdf.cover.pdf
```

on it. It's the whole path that will get passed to pdftk, so you'll end up with the cover PDFs in the same directory as the original files. (You could do something to get rid of the `.pdf.cover.pdf` extensions if you need to.)

Comment: @Cyrus You can't put `cover_` in front of the `'{}'`, because the `'{}'` matches the whole path, not just the basename. You'll end up with the `cover_` in front of the path. That's why I appended something instead.